# c++ compiler said that smart pointer's default_delete attempting to reference a deleted function when smart-ptr in a container as a item

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

This is a small practice project, I have write it in other programming language before. Now I am learning c++ with *TCPPPL* and Visual Studio 2019(c++14). So I try it again in c++.

This codes below is a part of the projects, I used `shared_ptr` as item of `list` in `class ebb_detial_item`, and let the shared_ptr be the type of a vector in `class rev_dates_handle` .

But the compiler always reports errors about "attempting to reference a deleted function"(i'm not deleted any function) and "can't convert argu1....":
[image: error list]

***categories_tbl.h***

```
#ifndef CATEGORIES_TBL
#define CATEGORIES_TBL

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include "ebb_string.h"
#include "ebb_detial_item.h"
#include "rev_dates_handle.h"

namespace ebb_impl
{
    class ebb_detial_item;

    class category
    {
    private:
        friend class ebb_detial_item;

        my_ebbstring::ebb_string name{};
        std::list<std::shared_ptr<ebb_impl::ebb_detial_item>> ebbtbl{};
        //   ^~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

        my_utility::id_pool::id_pool<unsigned> item_id_pool;

        ebb_rev_dates::rev_dates_handle rd_handle; 
        

    public:
        category(my_ebbstring::ebb_string name)
            : name{ name }, item_id_pool{ name }, rd_handle{ my_ebbstring::ebb_string{ "default" } } {   }
        ~category();

        category& add(ebb_detial_item* item_ptr);
        category& remove(ebb_detial_item* item_ptr);

        void set_rev_dates(
            my_ebbstring::ebb_string plan_name, 
            std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned>> new_plan_ptr);

    };
}

#endif /*CATEGORIES_TBL*/
```

***rev_dates_handle.h***

```
#ifndef REV_DATES_HANDLE_H
#define REV_DATES_HANDLE_H

#include <memory>
#include "ebb_string.h"
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

namespace ebb_impl
{
    namespace ebb_rev_dates
    {
        std::vector<unsigned> default_rev_dates_vec{
            0,    1,    2,    4,    7,
            10,   15,   16,   30,   31,
            90,   91,   150,  151,  152,
            210,  211,  270,  272,  360,
            370,  480,  490,  720,  750,
            1080, 1180, 1440
        };

        class rev_dates_handle
        {
        private:
            my_ebbstring::ebb_string name;
            std::unordered_map<my_ebbstring::ebb_string, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned>>> rev_tbl_ptrs{};

        public:
            rev_dates_handle(my_ebbstring::ebb_string handle_name);

            void add_tbl(
                my_ebbstring::ebb_string tbl_name, 
                std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned>> tbl_ptr);
            //       ^~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
            // this file is a header file so I need 
            // write std:: before vector, or use using indicate
            // but never do it in header file (namespace pollution)

            void change_tbl_rec(my_ebbstring::ebb_string name, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned>> new_tbl);
            static void change_gloable_default(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned>> usr_dft_tbl);

            // this is the unnormal function declaration
            std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned>> get_by_name(my_ebbstring::ebb_string name);

            void copy(my_ebbstring::ebb_string dst_name, my_ebbstring::ebb_string src_name);
        };
    }

}

#endif /*REV_DATES_HANDLE_H*/
```

Comment: Somewhere in the code not shown, you are using `unique_ptr`, and apparently doing so incorrectly. Show a [mcve]

Comment: you are right, my code is a mess, I forgot to change something dependences after i change other code.